# How can i enable checkbox by clicking Reset button in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, html

Hi i'm new to JS and i'm trying to do a BMI(Body/Mass Index) calculator for my website.

What i want to do is when a user clicks to Temizle(Reset) button disabled checkbox should be usable again. I wrote a function which is called "temizle" but it didn't work. I want to know 2 things for the solution.

1. If there is a easy way to do what i ask, please tell me.
2. If there is not, how should i change my code?

> ```
>  <html>
>         <head>
>         <script language="JavaScript">
>         <!--
>         function temizle(){
>     if(document.getElementById('e').disable=true)
>     {                       
>     document.getElementById('e').disable=false                                                          
>     }
>     if(document.getElementById('k').disable=true) 
>     {
>     document.getElementById('k').disable=false
>      } 
>     }
>     //-->
>     </script>
>     </head>
>     <body>
>     <form name="bmiForm">
>     Cinsiyetiniz: Erkek<input type="checkbox" id="e" name="erkek" onclick="if (this.checked) document.getElementById('k').disabled=true; else document.getElementById('k').disabled = false;"/> Kadın<input type="checkbox" id="k" name="kadın" onclick="if (this.checked) document.getElementById('e').disabled=true; else   document.getElementById('e').disabled = false;"/><br />  
>   Kilonuz(kg): <input type="text" name="kilo" size="10" /> Örn:75<br />
>   Boyunuz(cm): <input type="text" name="boy" size="10" /> Örn:183<br />
>   <input type="button" value="Kütle/Vücut İndeksi Hesapla" onClick="bmihesaplama()" /><br />
>   Kütle/Vücut İndeksiniz(BMI): <input type="text" name="bmi" size="10" /><br />
>   Bunun Anlamı: <input type="text" name="sonuc" size="45" /><br />
>   <input type="reset" value="Temizle" onclick="temizle()" />
>   </form>
>     </body>
>     </html>
> ```

Thx for your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You've typed `disable` as the property, but it's `disabled`.  You need to change that; it's important.

```
if(document.getElementById('k').disable=true)
```

Should also be changed; this is an *assignment*.  You could use `==`, but you can also just do:

```
if (document.getElementById('k').disabled)
```

http://jsfiddle.net/ExplosionPIlls/3AMtG/2/

Comment: @AaronBlenkush that has nothing to do with `disable` vs. `disabled`; the former is not a DOM Element property at all